# testing a service's call to $http with $httpBackend

Tags: angularjs

I have an AngularJS service for a restful API:

```
angular
  .module('app', [
  ])

  .service('api', ['$http', '$q', function APIService($http, $q) {
    this.get = function (dataProperty, params) {
      return $http({
          method: 'get',
          url: 'https://some.api/rest/',
          params: angular.extend({
            default_params...
          }, params)
        })
        .then(
          function (result) {
            if (result.data.status === 'ok') {
              return result.data[dataProperty];
            } else {
              return $q.reject(angular.extend(new Error(result.data.message), { result: result.data }));
            }
          },
          function (reason) {
            return $q.reject(angular.extend(new Error('AJAX request to the API failed'), { reason: reason.data }));
          });
    };
  }]);
```

I'm trying to test this api.get with the following:

```
describe('api', function () {
  var
    $httpBackend,
    service;

  beforeEach(module('app'));

  beforeEach(inject(function (_$httpBackend_, _api_) {
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    service = _api_;
  }));

  afterEach(function () {
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
  });

  it('', function () {
    $httpBackend
      .when('get', 'https://some.api/rest/')
      .respond({
        data: {
          status: 'ok'
        }
      });
    service.get('status', {});
    $httpBackend.flush();
    $httpBackend
      .expect('get', 'https://some.api/rest/');
  });
});
```

But I'm getting the error callback every time:

```
Error: AJAX request to the API failed in bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js (line 279)
```

Am I going about setting up the test correctly? I believe the `.when` and `.response` is used to fake the actual $http call, but I can't get the success callback to fire.

Comment: you have data.stat and data.status -- should be same?

Comment: Also there is no sense in using deffered in your code - it can be simplified.

Comment: Yes, they should have been both data.status. It was correct in my code, I just introduced that typo here when I simplified for SO.

Answer (score 0):

The two issues were `.when` not looking for the correct URL (because get params were thrown in I needed to make it a regex:

```
.when('GET', /https:\/\/api\.flickr\.com\/services\/rest\/.*/)
```

Then, the `.respond` doesn't need to be padded with a data object, it does that for you:

```
.respond({ stat: 'ok' });
```